# CSV into Excel with numeric codes of simbols

Tags: excel, csv, symbols

I have data in SCSV file like this:

```
1;"Concrete mixer 8м&#179;";9;;0
2;"Concrete mixer 10м&#179;";9;;0
3;"Screw &#248;15/17";11;86;3
4;"Screw &#248;15/17";11;104;3
5;"Shaft with a tip &#216;=25 мм";473;2035.66;3
...
```

When I open it in Excel I have strings in cells like this:

```
Concrete mixer 8м&#179;
```

But I need to see it like this:

```
Concrete mixer 8м3 (3 should be written as superscript)
```

Is it possible somehow to import them into Excel with showing special symbols (ex.3 as superscript and so on) instead of numeric codes?

Comment: Problem seems to be with encoding , which encoding type are you using/selecting while importing the csv?Try to open it in notepad and then save it as csv and again open in excel.

Comment: CSV-file with encoding cp1251. I use the same encoding (cp1251) when I import in Excel.  I try another encodings but they don't help.

Comment: Excel will not automatically transform `&#nnn` strings to their character equivalent. I believe your options will be to either encode the SCSV differently when you create it, or write a VBA or Power Query routine to decode it after importing the file into Excel.

Comment: I do not know if it is any help but using the function =CHAR(179) gives you 3 as superscript

Comment: You need to translate the HTML entities in the file first. You can do that online if you look for it, like [here](https://mothereff.in/html-entities) or [there](https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-html-entities-convertor.php)

Comment: @W_O_L_F, Thanks for your guess. But for some reason it does not work for me. When I use "=CHAR(179)" , I get a symbol like "i" , Instead of 3 as superscript. Besides, I need to do it automatically.

Comment: Theo, @Ron Rosenfeld,Thank you guys for yous answers. In which file-format should I encode my file? And how can I do it automatically?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your CSV generator, but you should choose to encode in such a way that you are getting the actual character, in place of the URL encoded characters that you are having a problem with.

Comment: Also, the symbol that is returned for the formula `=CHAR(179)` will be dependent on the font you are using.  What is the font in that cell?  You could automate the conversion by using Power Query or VBA to automate the import process, but you'll still need a font that has the same code-letter mapping as does the original document.